# How to use github icon set on fontello

Tags: github, webfonts, icon-fonts, fontello

[Fontello](http://fontello.com/) has an area where you can drag custom fonts onto.
[GitHub style page here](https://github.com/styleguide/css/7.0) shows they have a custom font I want to use on that fontello can someone please help me to import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to GitHub Style page HERE
2. Open the inspector `Ctrl + Shift + C`
3. Click on `Fonts`
4. Click on "See all fonts used in this page"
5. Find `octicons` section
6. Highlight and copy (with Ctrl+C, cant right click here) that box below >Used as: "octicons"
   [image: github icon set import to fontelo step 6]
7. Open notepad and paste it there.
8. Find the `format(svg)` and copy it
   [image: github iconset import to fontello step 8]
9. Go back to firefox, type in `http://github.com/` and then paste the string you copied so now in URL bar it says `https://github.com//assets/octicons-cdc456dbc5906e59b8c4d1c649a4b734fb0fd97b.svg#octicons`
10. Hit enter and now right click in the page after it loads and go view source
    [image: github iconset import to fontello step 10]
11. Save this source to your drive
    [image: github iconset import to fontello step 11]
12. Now go to Fontello tab and then drag the downloaded file into the area on Fontello site where it says "Drag custom SVG icons or SVG font here" on fontello
    [image: github iconset import to fontello step 12]
    DONE. Wait and magically all the github icons are now available to you!! Its grouped as "Custom Icons"
    [image: github iconset import to fontello step done]

Super cool!!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I love the GitHub icon font "Octicons" too. Unfortunately as far as I know they're assumed to not freely available to the public - see here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/191#issuecomment-6180040

That said - I just did some source file snooping and grabbed the TTF and other files here if you wanna try this on fontello? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7951258/fonts/octicons-from-github.com_20140302.zip

PS: If you do find a way to get a hold of them legitamitely please post an update though!

Comment: Hey man i figured it out!! THanks so much for the reply. Ill post solution below. :)

Comment: Awesome. Man I am so obsessed w/fontello - love it. BTW - you mind ticking my reply as useful/answer? Technically I did get you the font files (same way you grabbed them btw).

Comment: Thanks your snooping idea helped me figure it out :)But you didn't tell me how to snoop just left that up to me, but I'll tick anyways for the effort! :)